# Required Type "Loan', Given String

Tags: java, oop

So i have fallen into a small problem, i am trying to create a Loan object by using the the instances created in my Loan class, however i cannot seem to call them as it keeps i am using a string.

```
@Override
public void loadData(Library library) throws IOException, LibraryException {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(RESOURCE))) {
        int line_idx = 1;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] properties = line.split(SEPARATOR, -1);
            try {

                Loan patron = properties[0];
                Loan book = properties[1];
                LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(properties[2]);
                LocalDate dueDate = LocalDate.parse(properties[3]);
                Loan loan = new Loan(patron, book, startDate, dueDate);
                library.addLoan(loan);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                throw new LibraryException("Unable to parse patron id " + properties[0] + " on line " + line_idx
                        + "\nError: " + ex);
            }
            line_idx++;
        }
    }
}
```

For 'Loan book' and 'Loan patron' i am getting these errors. If anyone could help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory: a `String` is not a `Loan`. In Oop-Terms: a `String` is not a sub-class of `Loan`, neither is any super-class of `String`. Thus, a `String`-value cannot be assigned to a `Loan`-reference.

Comment: Can you send us a source code of Loan class? I guess there's a constructor that allows you to use string, may be something like Loan patron = new Loan(properties[0]); EDIT: As I see you create a Loan object later, so I guess you just have to change Loan type to String

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m2SyDSqW

Comment: Im trying to create a loan object which loads the patron iid, book and the startdate and duedate of the loan

Comment: The only constructor of Loan class uses Patron and Book objects, so patreon and book variables have can't be Loan

Comment: But still I don't have Book and Patreon source code, so I don't know how to initialize them

Comment: book :https://pastebin.com/R6kt67eR @IksSki im just having a tough time been trying to figure this out for awhile and cannot seem to get anyfurther

Comment: Just look at the Book class constructor [public Book(int id, String title, String author, String publicationYear) ]

Comment: To sum up: The patron variable can't be String, it has to be Patron, and the book var has to be Book. In order to create a Book variable, you have to put in following items: int id, String title, String author, String publicationYear. After that, just repeat the process with Patreon (I guess the constructor is similar)

Comment: @KaziIlyas The book variable can be created like that: Book book = new Book(someId, title, author, publicationYear); EDIT: What exactly is in the properties array?

Comment: The array holds the properties such as the PatronID, BookID, Startdate and Duedate. I need to retrieve the information when typing in the borrow command and loading it in that order @IksSki

Comment: In order to create a Book instance, you have to have id, title, author, publicationYear. Without this information you can't initialize it. EDIT: If you really want to, you can just do it like this: Book book = new Book(YOURID, "", "", ""); Where YOURID is your id from array

Comment: https://pastebin.com/H37Xf3mi @IksSki here is the class i use to create a loan, im hoping its right. Also thanks for your time

Comment: btw i dont want a book instance i want a Loan that holds all the information such as the the patronid who is borrowing, the book which is borrowed and start and duedate of the loan

Comment: book and patron variable can't be Loan. As I see you are creating Loan a little bit further, BUT if you want to create a Loan instance, you have to put in the constructor following variables: [Patron patron, Book book, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate dueDate]. The first variable is type of Patreon and the second is Book, not Loan

Comment: @IksSki i've tried before that but doesnt work :(

Comment: Let me do the magic. Change "Loan book = properties[1];" to "Book book = new Book(properties[1], "", "", "");" Do you still see error on that line?

Comment: errors :( someone kill me xd

Comment: just post your code after doing this

Comment: Book var should be done like this: https://pastebin.com/EcydLgvG

Comment: Here is abit more information about what im trying to do @IksSki https://pastebin.com/8HgE9u4p

Comment: @IksSki tried it like that says : Given String required Int

Comment: Change  Book book = new Book(properties[1], "", "", "");  to                 Book book = new Book(Integer.valueOf(properties[1]), "", "", "");

Comment: Thanks for your help, theres just too many problems atm, if you want i coulld send you the whole project and you could maybe have a look at it, im assuming its something small however im just not at that level @IksSki

Comment: @KaziIlyas you can just upload your project to github if it's not-that-private and share a link here